How to export disappear animation in glb with multiple animation in blender?
i have a doubt
i am working on 3floor building animation,
i have to export different animation in single glb
if i selected ground floor in glb the other 2 floor (first and second) floor should be disabled ,
if i selected 1st floor in glb the ground floor and 2nd floor should be disabled ,
if i selected 2nd floor in glb the ground floor and 1st floor should be disabled ,
all this thing should be done in single glb is it possible
if there is any possible ways please help me out.enter image description here
I want to disappear in model which floor is not selected.
I requirements is
when i select any one floor i want to animate only selected floor , remaining floor should disappear.
For reference please check this reference...
My requirement.
